# python function syntax error

Tags: python, function

```
import time
arxi=time.time()

number=(int(input('Dwse arithmo'))

def function1(x):
    for i in range(1,x):
        z1=random.randint(1,6)
        z2=random.randint(1,6)
    if z1=z2:
        w=open("diplo.txt","w")
        print(z1,file=w)
    else:
        f=open("mono.txt","w")
        print(z1,',',z2,file=f)

zaria(number)
f.close()
w.close()  
print("O Xronos einai:",time.time()-arxi)
```

I'm getting this:

```
def function1(x): Encountered "def" at line 7, column 1. Was expecting one of:     "(" ...     ")" ...     "[" ...     "," ...     "." ...     "+" ...     "-" ...     "*" ...     "/" ...     "//" ...     "<<" ...     ">>" ...     "%" ...     "^" ...     "|" ...     "&" ...     ">" ...     
 "<" ...     "==" ...     "<=" ...     ">=" ...     "!=" ...     "or" ...     "and" ...     "not" ...     "is" ...     "in" ...     "if" ...     "," ...
```

Don't know if I'm really blind or something doesn't go well with my Python installation.

Comment: oh god . thanks sir. seems my brain is too melted atm.

Answer (score 2):

`if z1=z2:` is your problem you need `==`

and it seems like you have an indenting issue. Which might be just on the website:

```
 for i in range(1,x):
    z1=random.randint(1,6)
    z2=random.randint(1,6)
    if z1==z2:
      w=open("diplo.txt","a") # also you may want to append instead of write?
      print(z1,file=w)
    else:
      f=open("mono.txt","a")   # also you may want to append instead of write?
      print(z1,',',z2,file=f)
```

Comment: This is **not** the cause of the error message however. This is an **additional** problem. There are at least 2 more issues in the code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters True. You have displayed them quite well I +1'ed

Answer (score 1):

You have a parenthesis too many:

```
number=(int(input('Dwse arithmo'))
#      ^
```

That one opening parenthesis is not closed , and entirely redundant here. But because it is not closed Python looks for the rest of the expression it is expecting to follow.

You have more problems beyond that however, as the following line will also throw an error:

```
if z1=z2:
```

You cannot assign in an expression; you probably meant to use `==` there.

Next, your file `close()` calls are in the wrong place; `f` and `w` won't be defined by the time those lines are reached.

Remove them altogether and use the `with` statement instead:

```
with open("diplo.txt", "w") as w:
    print(z1, file=w)
```

and

```
with open("mono.txt","w") as f:
    print(z1, ',', z2, file=f)
```

Now `w` and `f` are closed *automatically* when the `with` block ends.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing wrong in if statement. Check here [Python Equality Check Difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220141/python-equality-check-difference) You need to use `==` statement to compare.